# Ambigous occurence Show

Tags: haskell, typeclass

When i try to create an `instance` of the typeclass `Show` i get the places where i used `show` highlighted with the following message:

```
Ambiguous occurrence `show'
    It could refer to either `Prelude.show',
                             imported from `Prelude' at [..]\Company.hs   (and originally defined in `GHC.Show')
                          or `Company.show',
                             defined at [..]\Company.hs:29:5
```

**Company.hs**

```
module Company where
    import Data.List

    data Worker=Worker{
        age::Int,
        name::String,
        title::Title,
        income::Int
    } 


    names=["age","name","title","income"]
    accesors=[show . age,show . name, show . title,show .income]

    data Title=Manager | Dev | Tester deriving (Show)

    data Company=Company{
        cname::String,
        people::[Man],
        yf::Int
    }deriving (Show)

    instance Show Man where 
    show w = intercalate "," (zipWith (\name acc->name++":"++acc w) names accesors)
```

**P.S** Added all the module which I just load in the Prelude.The  error is with the `show` applied on all `accesors`.

Comment: [Seems to run fine when adding the definition of `names` which seems to be missing and `intercalate` from `Data.List`.](https://tio.run/##bVE9a8MwEN31Kx6ig43dkHY0uEuzBFo6JNAhzSAcNRa1JSOJmPTjt7sn2akzVCDd3dPp3btTLdyHbJphUG1nrMdKeLF4Us4nSntpK9EIL1PGDoTjWeiS9hfDtMRRFsVa@/wP0aIlaOOt0scZ9co3BG@DmVGlK9OOBBH7wVgmpoVCRG/xjZU80bmVjgThIK06ETmSTW36i7JH03ZCn8vJzgqr/wV10nRB0Y6q7Gf4/H6lhjFRVdIZ68qdo1pYhH7zyQ28OaYg9jfdjF3twVhIobecXvEcPITBxuTgjJl8z5jSzgtdSYSewpjR19JKRCGRtkeJqx8BzzmST9W9Kl8jeQvcILm3D8HLMl7wLKMYfRqVOlx6oYm1QmkUBdYvSNIxKtHRgDxuYvH7JfjWtByXP7hb0hqGXw) Also in Haskell comments start `--`, not `//`.

Comment: Also you should use `Show` and `Read` for printing/parsing Haskell expressions of values. For special printing use different functions/typeclasses that fit the need. (such as `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` from the `aeson` package).

Comment: Is there any linter or something that I can use to stop getting indentation parse errors?I am using VSCode on Windows.

Comment: Yes, install `hlint`. :)

Comment: I have installed `Haskell-linter` but not `hlint` thanks.

Comment: I have not had any luck getting `haskell-linter` to work in my vscode projects, but `hlint` works when I follow the installation instructions precisely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**After your edit:** Your problem is due to indentation. You need to add at least one space before `show w = ...`, otherwise it will become a top-level definition inside the Company module, causing there to be two separate `show` definitions of which one is not overloaded, rather than a part of the `instance Show Man` definition.

**Before your edit:** Your code doesn't execute because of missing parts, but adding those missing parts it also does not produce the warnings you're giving:

```
module Main where

import Data.List

data Title = Manager | Dev | Tester deriving (Show)

data Man = Man { _age    :: Int
               , _name   :: String
               , _title  :: Title
               , _income :: Int
               }

instance Show Man where
  show m = intercalate "," (zipWith (\name acc -> name ++ ":" ++ acc m) names accessors)

data Company = Company { _cname  :: String
                       , _people :: [Man]
                       , _yf     :: Int
                       }

instance Show Company where
  show (Company cname people yf) =
    intercalate "\n  " $
      ("Company (" ++ cname ++ ", " ++ show yf ++ "):") : map show people

names :: [String]
names = ["age", "name", "title", "income"]

accessors :: [Man -> String]
accessors = [show . _age, show . _name, show . _title, show . _income]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print alice
  print bob
  print (Company "Alice & Bob's" [alice, bob] 1)

alice, bob :: Man
alice = Man 41 "Alice" Manager 41000
bob = Man 42 "Bob" Manager 42000
```

Gives:

```
$ ./show
age:41,name:"Alice",title:Manager,income:41000
age:42,name:"Bob",title:Manager,income:42000
Company (Alice & Bob's, 1):
  age:41,name:"Alice",title:Manager,income:41000
  age:42,name:"Bob",title:Manager,income:42000
```

Although you would probably be quite happy with `deriving (Show)` for each of these.

Comment: Thank you very much it was due to indentation.